# How can I release stdin (pass it to the terminal again) after the input pipe is broken?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, sh

I want to pipe the output of a command to another command, but I want to be able to type things into stdin like I can without a pipe when the pipe is broken by the first command.

`cat file.txt | python -i script.py` will exit the python interpreter immediately when the file is fully processed.

Comment: `cat file.txt /dev/tty | python -i script.py`

Comment: If command is more complicated than `cat`: `mycommand file.txt | cat - /dev/tty | python -i script.py`

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a .txt file, I suggest another way to process to your demand:

```
import sys
inFile = sys.argv[1]

with open(inFile,'r') as i:
    lines = i.readlines()
```

You can call this program by running:

```
$ python script.py file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I guess it was an XY problem.